# C++\Qt class object in another class

Tags: c++, c, qt

I having problems using one class object in another one. The problem is - i having LNK2019 error at my soapserver.cpp function. But first thing first.

Here is the header of my first class

```
//datalayer.h
#include <QObject>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QVariant>

class DataLayer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    bool set_delivered(const QString& UCID, const QString& Key, QVariant &result);
    explicit DataLayer(QObject *parent = 0);
    QString getLastError() const{return lastError;}

private:
    QString lastError;

};
```

I am also have set_delivered defined at cpp

```
    //datalayer.cpp
DataLayer::DataLayer(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE","DB");
    //db.databaseName();
    //db.hostName();
    //db.userName();
    //db.password();

    q = new QSqlQuery(db);
    //q->prepare(""); //not implemented yet
}

DataLayer::~DataLayer()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("DB",false);
    if(db.open())
    {
       db.close();
    }
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("DB");
}
bool DataLayer::set_delivered(const QString &UCID, const QString &Key, QVariant &result)
{
    result.clear();
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("DB",false);
    if(!db.open())
    {
        lastError = db.lastError().text();
        return false;
    }
    q->prepare("INSERT INTO ActiveCall VALUES(:UCID,:Time,NULL,NULL,:Key)");
    q->bindValue(":UCID",UCID);
    q->bindValue(":Time",QTime::currentTime().toString("HH:mm:ss:zzz"));
    q->bindValue(":Key",Key);
    if(!q->exec())
    {
        lastError = q->lastError().text();
        return false;
    }
    q->next();
    result = q->value("Time").toString();
    db.close();
    return true;
}
```

Let's jump to another class, mysoapserver

```
//mysoapserver.h
#include "soap/soapKursWebService.h"
#include "soap/soapH.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <qdebug.h>
#include "datalayer.h"// I'm including datalayer header here

class MySOAPServer : public QObject, public KursWebService
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MySOAPServer(QObject* parent = 0);
    int delivered(int UCID, int DeviceNum, int &result);
private:
    DataLayer* r;// creating of the class object

};
```

And, the main part, the cpp of this class

```
//mysoapserver.cpp
int MySOAPServer::delivered(int UCID, int DeviceNum, int &result)//вызов доставлен, но трубку не снял, в табличку время начала
{
    qDebug()<<"delivered "<<UCID<<" "<< DeviceNum;
    QVariant res = 0;
    QString UCID_S = QString::number(UCID);
    QString Key_S = QString::number(DeviceNum);
    bool ok = r->set_delivered(UCID_S,Key_S,res);//LNK2019 here
    if(!ok)
        result = r->getLastError().toInt();//magicly works here
    else
        result = res.toInt();
    return SOAP_OK;
}
```

I know, i do something stupid with class objects, but i am complitly lost now. Thanks you in advance for help!

EDIT: added my .pro file and my datalayer.cpp

pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-04-19T02:23:22
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui network sql

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Server_MVSC_Kurs_III
TEMPLATE = app
DEFINES += WITH_PURE_VIRTUAL
INCLUDEPATH += \
    C:/Qt/gsoap-2.8.15/gsoap/

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    ipcserver.cpp \
    mysoapserver.cpp \
    soap/soapC.cpp \
    soap/soapKursWebService.cpp \
    soap/stdsoap2.cpp \
    datalayer.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    ipcserver.h \
    mysoapserver.h \
    soap/soapH.h \
    soap/soapKursWebService.h \
    soap/soapStub.h \
    soap/stdsoap2.h \
    soap/KursWeb.nsmap \
    datalayer.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I think the `LNK2019 here` (unresolved external symbol) in mysoapserver.cpp needs a solution.

Comment: Show your porject file. You should link your DataLayer module into the project to work. 2 Show your DataLayer.cpp fully

Comment: Sorry, yes, i have LNK2019 at bool ok = r->set_delivered(UCID_S,Key_S,res); of my soapserver.cpp. I am also edited my code and added the pro file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be helpful if there was a little bit more information, but from what is there...

I think the problem is with your header files.

You have to put the in  the mysoapserver.cpp file:

```
#include "datalayer.h"
```

and in the mysoapserver.h header file put:

```
class DataLayer;
```

---

Explanation:

The error Unresolved Symbol is referring to the DataLayer object, since the file  mysoapserver.cpp has no idea that DataLayer is even a thing.  at least according to what you posted for mysoapserver.cpp

You also need to add in to mysoapserver.cpp

```
#include "mysoapserver.h"
```

Comment: @Senso Hakai - No problem. Qt is weird when it comes to header files. Who knows why. ;)